# getting not a function in Accessing instance methods from different class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two class in different modules one is global class to have every created User class information in the Global object. but getting `global.pushUserInformation is not a function` by
this way

~/project/Global.js

```
    class Global{
         constructor(){
             this.userInformation = {} 
         }
         pushUserInformation(useInf){
             this.userInformation[useInf[p]] = "Sd" ;
         }
    }
module.exports = Global ;
```

~/project/User.js

```
    const global = require("./index.js) 
               class User {
                     constructor(){
                          this.userMain = {}
                     }
                     register(useInf){
                          global.pushUserInformation(useInf); 
                     } 
                }
    
module.exports = User ;
```

~/project/index.js

```
    const User  = require("./User.js")
    const Global = require("./Global.js) 
    
    const global = new Global() 
    const us = { p : 95} 
    const user1 = new User() 
    user1.register(us) ;
    
module.exports = global
```

Is there any other way of doing this to have a global object for every instance created?

Comment: I hope those missing quotation marks are typos, which only exist in this question?

Comment: Continuing from what question? Questions on Stack Overflow should be self-contained and not depend on anything else.

Comment: If you're using es6 modules, you shouldn't be using `module.exports` and `require`; that's CommonJS modules. ES modules use `export ...` and `import ... from ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

static keyword is the answer.

Can use the main class method anywhere by declaring method and properties with static.